# Как ответить та этом сайте?

Tags: обсуждение

Хочу ответить на вопрос, но не могу найти кнопку для ответа. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: В самом конце страницы есть поле, туда вводите свой ответ

Comment: @user7860670 Она уже смогла ответить тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416676/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0 :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот она, возможно слишком большой масштаб экрана

Answer (score 0):

Ответить на некоторые вопросы которые требуют улучшения невозможно, т.к. они, собственно говоря, требуют улучшения, вы можете попытаться исправить вопрос, и тогда возможно кнопка отправки ответа появится (Если правку примут). Также вопрос может быть историческим наследием Stackoverflow, но не соответствовать правилам и нормам сообщества, так что на него невозможно будет ответить.