# Стоит ли жаловаться на ответы, авторы которого не совсем поняли тему вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение

### **Предупреждение: представленный в виде ссылки вопрос является примером. Наверняка эта проблема касается не одного ответа.**

---

Встретив вопрос [Как ответить та на этом сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12013/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5), стало понятно, что ответ

> Ответить на некоторые вопросы которые требуют улучшения невозможно,
> т.к. они, собственно говоря, требуют улучшения, вы можете попытаться
> исправить вопрос, и тогда возможно кнопка отправки ответа появится
> (Если правку примут). Также вопрос может быть историческим наследием
> Stackoverflow, но не соответствовать правилам и нормам сообщества, так
> что на него невозможно будет ответить.

не подходит, так как спрашивающего интересовало нахождение кнопки, ответ же повествовал о возможности и смысле (стоит ли их давать) ответов на вопросы некоторых категорий.

Казалось бы, очень подходит причина тревоги "не является ответом". Но этом не совсем так, ведь 1) ответ был на эту же тему 2) он сопутствующий, автор ответа допустил более глубокую трактовку. Главная проблема состоит в том, что в ответе отсутствует основной ответ :) Было бы там, в нашем случае и инструкции по нахождению этой несчастной кнопки, то ответ был бы идеален. В существующем виде он не так хорош.

Как обратить внимание автора ответа?

Есть, конечно, банальное решение - комментарии. Можно сообщить автору ответа, что его творение можно усовершенствовать. Но, может быть, есть что-нибудь получше?

Comment: Не вижу причин что-то делать с ответом из примера.

Comment: бывает так, что ответ на вопрос правильный, абсолютно правильный, но вот только спрашивающий "недотягивает до понимания ответа" и минусует (а иногда и окружающие). С другой стороны, может быть ответ, который соответствует уровню вопрошающего, но вот только окружающим он не нравится (слишком просто, нет по сути и так далее) и так появляются вопросы, которые заминусованы, но приняты.  Вывод - если кажется, что ответ какой то "не такой", не нужно думать, что он "неверный", он может быть для "другой целевой аудитории".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"не является ответом" это не индикатор правильности ответа. Ответ может быть не верным, но при этом ответ есть ответ. Автор вопроса может быть не согласен, но при этом ответ есть ответ. "не является ответом" - это тревога, что в сообщении вообще нет информации по теме, это может быть "спасибо", дополнительная информация, которая дополняет сам вопрос, другой вопрос, восклицания такие как "у меня та же проблема, есть решение?" и прочее.

> В существующем виде он не так хорош

Это же субъективное восприятие. Для вас это так, для другого человека ваше `хорош`, не будет приемлимым.

Складывается впечатление (без негативной подоплеки), что вы оцениваете по своей шкале мер и весов. Но ведь пользователи разные, пишут по разному, отвечают по разному. Я здесь пишу ответы только потому, что в реальной жизни мои объяснения не понимает никто. Я учусь объяснять, чтобы было понятно не только мне. Но от этого мои ответы не становятся `не является ответом`. Они могут быть косоязычны, с отклонениями от темы, частенько с ошибками из-за скорости чтения задания и пропускания текста кусками.

Комментарии - это один из инструментов обратить внимание, голосование - другой. Если ответ пошел в минус, значит, что-то не так. Но и с другой стороны, если не нравится ответ - это не причина ставить минус. А вот если в нем ошибка и ты указал в комментарии и нет ответа и исправления по этому поводу, тогда и только тогда ставлю минус. На самом деле очень редко на ответы.

А вот вносить изменения в ответ автора с попыткой поправить его или *усовершенствовать* ответ - плохой тон и неуважение к его труду. Так не надо делать

вот вам пример ответа, где тревога `не является ответом` вполне себе релеванта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]